# Java Generics in Stream

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I know that you use <? extends> wildcard when you only **get** values out of a collection.

Suppose there's Animal superclass and Dog and Cat subclasses. Basically I want to have a list that contains dogs and cats. I found out I can do the following:

```
List<? extends Animal> animalList;
List<Dog> dogList = getDogs();
List<Cat> catList = getCats();

animalList = Stream.concat(dogList.stream(), catList.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())

// Do things according to its type
for (Animal animal : animalList) {
    if (animal instance of Dog) {...}
    if (animal instance of Cat) {...}
}
```

The above code compiles. So does it violate the rule in the sense that I'm *writing* values to `animalList`?

Comment: You're not writing anything to `animalList`. You create it using the stream. The stream's type uses the common type for `dogList` and `catList`, and is therefore `Stream<Animal>`. You collect it to a `List<Animal>`. You assign that to the `animalList` variable, but you don't write anything to the list afterwards.

Comment: Are you doubting the statement that "you can't write to `List<? extends Animal>`"?

Comment: @Sweeper Right, that's exactly what I'm asking and confused about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Stream.concat(dogList.stream(), catList.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

This creates a `List<Animal>`. Crucially, not a `List<? extends Animal>`. Try it:

```
List<Animal> = ... all that ...
```

works fine.

`List<Animal>` doesn't mean that everything in it was made using literally `new Animal()`. You can have a `List<Animal>` that contains solely `Cat` instances. Those are all animals, that's fine.

The 'point' of `? extends` and all that is when you deal with the lists themselves, not with the things within them. Here's specifically why:

```
List<Animal> x = new ArrayList<Cat>();
x.add(new Dog());
Cat z = x.get(0);
```

Triple check the above code but it explains exactly why `? extends` (and `? super`) exists. Generics must be **invariant**, anything else leads to broken code. The above code must not compile because it makes no sense. As written, it indeed doesn't compile - line 1 isn't allowed. You can 'make it work' by writing `List<? extends Animal> x = new ArrayList<Cat>()` which compiles fine, but now `x.add(new Dog()` won't.

The difference is this:

a `List<Animal>` variable is pointing at some list that is actually some list of specifically `<Animal>` and not some subtype or supertype of Animal. It might be a `LinkedList<Animal>` or an `ArrayList<Animal>`, that's fine, but not an `ArrayList<Cat>`. With that known, when you 'read' from it, you get Animal objects out, and when you write to it, Animal is fine.

a `List<? extends Animal>` variable on the other hand is some list that is of Animal **or some subtype of Animal**. It could be a `LinkedList<Dog>`. Given that fact, when you read, `Animal` is fine (`Animal f = thatList.get(0)` compiles fine), but you can't write anything to it. It might be a list of Dogs, but it could also be a list of Cats, and absolutely no object is therefore save (Except, trivially, literally the expression `null`, written out like that: `thatList.add(null)` compiles. And isn't useful, of course).

You assign your `List<Animal>` expression to a variable of type `List<? extends Animal>` which is fine. And needless; `List<Animal> x = Stream.concat....` would have worked just as well.